# why does a set of commands in batch tend to stop after running only some of the commands?

Tags: maven, command-line, batch-file

The objective of my batch file is to do "mvn clean install", copy some environment files somewhere, then start the localhost server.

This is my batch file:

```
REM # change the following dirs accordingly
set webapp_dir=C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk
echo "moving to webapps project dir"
cd %webapp_dir%
echo "mvn clean install"
mvn clean install

---------------------it seems to finish the maven install then just stops
---------------------------i dont really wanna write 2 batch files just for this

set env_dir=C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk\etc\environment\dev\yao
set class_dir=C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk\webapps-dist\target\classes
cd %env_dir%
copy /y env.conf.bat %class_dir%
echo "copying env.conf file"

msg * maven install complete, the env.conf has been copied

set run_dir=C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk\webapps-dist\target\classes\jboss-as\bin
cd %run_dir%
echo "starting the server, run server 0.0.0.0"
run.bat -c server -b 0.0.0.0
```

When I say stop i mean [image: this]
So it there a way to run everything here in one batch file?

Comment: When you say "stops", does it just hang, or does the batch file end after `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables the console just ends where the install completes with its success message.. added screenshot.. it should have also went on to copy my env files then start the localhost server...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try changing `mvn clean install` to `call mvn clean install`.

If `mvn` is another batch file, control won't get returned to your original batch file unless you explicitly call it with `call`.

Comment: Window never ceases to amaze me. Highly intuitive!

Comment: Is there a way to call mvn install from a different directory? For instance, my bat needs to do this: 
`cd %dp%
call mvn clean install ...`
is there any way to do `%dp%\mvn clean install`?

Comment: @TravisHeeter it's been a good long while, but off the top of my head you could try `"%dp%\mvn" clean install`, making sure you use the quotations so that the path can handle any spaces in it.